# Editing a Custom Block

Tags: 6, blocks

I have taken over the maintenance of a site that was built with Drupal 6.x

Prior to this I have no Drupal experience, so I am rolling up my sleeves and getting stuck into how Drupal works, with vcarying degrees of success.

My problem is this:

There is a menu on the site which I would have presumed was primary navigation, but it turns out to be a block.

I need to edit this menu, but there are no options to do so under blocks, there is a configure button beside it, but this does not allow me to edit its content. There is no delete option shown either, as I notice some blocks have this option and others dont.

Any ideas where I can find the content of this block so that I can edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the delete option in the block configuration page for those blocks that have been created using Add Block option (in Admin >> Site Building >> Block). In your case the menu block in question might have been created programatically using [hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_block/6) or any other means that I'm not aware of and the Delete link might not appear due to the same. Suggest that you identify the code/module responsible for generating the block before you proceed on to anything. Also if you wish to replace this block with something more easily configurable I'd suggest using [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) which I feel is a wonderful module